# React Native Image not being centered with View

Tags: css, image, react-native, flexbox

I am trying to center an `Image` within a `View` both horizontally and vertically the problem is that no matter what I put in the code it still seems to be in the same position all the time. I have this code for another `View` from another screen and it's exactly how I need it to be, however for the other pages it's not responding.

Here is my code:

```
<View style={styles.header}>
        <Icon
            raised
            name='chevron-left'
            type='octicon'
            color='#f50'
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
            containerStyle={{ alignSelf:'flex-end', marginRight:20, marginTop:-60 }}/>
        <Image source={Logo} style={{resizeMode:'stretch', width:50, height:50, alignItems:'center', marginTop:30, position:'absolute'}}/>
       </View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        header:{
        backgroundColor:'#ff4714', 
        height:SCREEN_HEIGHT/8,
        flexDirection: 'row' 

    }
});
```

EDIT: I've removed all the styling for the `<Image>` except for `width` and `height` and the image stays at the same place. I don't know what to make of this

Here is an expo snack https://snack.expo.io/SyCO!ree8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add justifyContent:'center' and alignSelf:'center' to your image style,

Just check the code :

```
 <View style={{
        flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
      }}>
       <Image source={{uri:'https://source.unsplash.com/random'}} style={{height:50,width:50,alignSelf:'center'}}         />
      </View>
```

And this is expo snack : [expo-snack](https://snack.expo.io/HkI8kNxg8)

UPDATE:

HERE IS MY UPDATED EXPO SNACK:

[check here](https://snack.expo.io/B1zAcSge8)

Hope it helps

Comment: I've edited my question, for some reason nothing I do changes the position of the image

Comment: share an expo snack for the same please

Comment: hey , check my answer once ive updated the link. do tell me if you have . any doubts

Comment: It works! I have no idea how the last `View` affects the Image in the slightest way, but for some reason this just doesn't work without it haha. Thank you

Comment: thats because its given flex directoin row. and you need 3 components for the second one to be in center. so a dummy view to place the image in center

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center'
```

to your `header` style

You might also need to add `flex:1`, depending on the state of your `View`

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. I've edited my question for more insight